# What would be the repercussions about lying about age in apple developer program?

Tags: developer-program

I cannot enroll in the Apple Developer program because I am under 18. What would be the repercussions if I lied about my age and then signed up?

Comment: Just use a parent's name and birthday until you're old enough to enroll yourself.

Comment: Without specifying what repercussions you are concerned with, this is a bit too broad to guess what you’re asking. An edit will help us help you if desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create apps, you can download *Xcode* and do that for free. You can even deploy the apps to your own devices.

If you want to sell apps on the *App Store*, it takes more than just signing-up for the Dev Program; you have to sign contracts and bank agreements. You could be susceptible to charges of fraud and/or misrepresentation.